Why was my question about using PHP and the open source Git Updater API closed for being "not about programming"?
How to prevent an existing WordPress.org plugin from overriding a plugin that's being updated with "Git Updater"?
Please tell me how this question warranted being closed for being "not about programming" when it's literally about PHP programming language, Git Updater (an open source PHP/WordPress project), and how to avoid code conflicts in these different codebases?

Regardless, the bigger question is why this question was closed, and how it could possibly be classified as "not about programming"... there are clearly a few people on this platform trying to harass me on a weekly basis and it's a shame.

"Here are clearly a few people on this platform trying to harass me on a weekly basis and it's a shame." - Considering my first reaction after reading the question you are asking about, is that it was indeed out of scope, since it appeared to be a WordPress configuration issue I would disagree with your conclusion.

@SecurityHound Just because you hate WordPress doesn't mean that my PHP question is unrelated to programming...

@SecurityHound it's not a WordPress configuration issue. I disagree with this users' wild accusations, but the question is about using the plugin's API to accomplish a specific behavior

The plugin is written in PHP. My question is about PHP. Please stop rewording my question to make it sound like I work for Git Updater or something.

"The plugin is written in PHP". That's not relevant to opening or closing the question. "My question is about PHP". No, it's not. It's about this specific plugin's API. I'm rephrasing the question for clarity. I have no idea who you work for, and my intent is that it's easier to see the merits of the linked question.

@yivi - Yes; I am aware it's NOT a WordPress configuration but that does not mean that wasn't the first thing that popped into my head.

Your edits continually make the question worse. You are intent in not letting other users help you. Suit yourself.

Your edits continually try to make it seem like I'm a spammer, for asking about an open source PHP extension on a programming website.

I am not doing anything of the sort. I was trying to help you. I have no idea how you get the idea that my edits "made you seem like a spammer". You keep focusing in the wrong parts, which make the question less likely to succeed. That Git Updated is "an open source PHP extension" is irrelevant. What's relevant is that you are trying to program using its API, that's all. It could be commercial and closed source, and would still be the same thing, and equally on-topic. Have fun. Bye.

@yivi I assume OP is referring to their previous Meta question in which they were accused of spamming for referencing an open-source project that they actually do work on. I'm guessing they're still upset about the whole incident.

@F1Krazy Accurate on all counts.

@F1Krazy Frankly, if that's the case, it's even crazier. The way they are presenting this question is not helping the way they are being perceived at all. I tried to make the question better so it actually defended the topicality of the linked question... but they insist in leaving up a version which is a ranty mess in all fronts.

Leaving in the name of the programming languages that my question was about, when I'm being accused of posting questions that have nothing to do with programming languages, is important to me, thank you.

I came across your question and cast a close vote because, after reading it, it didn't seem strictly about programming. It might have been more suitable for WordPress Stack Exchange. Unfortunately, old questions can't be migrated to another Stack Exchange site, and therefore the only option was to simply vote to close it.
If my analysis of your question is incorrect and your question is indeed on-topic, I apologize for that. At this time, other community members have already voted to reopen it.
With that said, I feel necessary to address this comment of yours:

there are clearly a few people on this platform trying to harass me on a weekly basis

The closure of that question has nothing to do with harassment. Nor me neither the other person who originally voted to close that question are attempting to target you.
You have already complained (multiple times) about possible actions on this site that may be targeted against you and those are being reviewed — despite, frankly, the evidence available to moderators is rather weak. However this instance is in no way about harassment toward you.

"it's the same 2 people going around down-voting all of my content on this platform" - you can't possibly know that, as downvotes are anonymous.

@F1Krazy You bring up a good argument for abandoning anonymous down-voting so that serial harassment can be more easily traced.

Further, if PHP and GitHub API are not considered "programming" I'm wondering which community on the SE network would be better suited to such a question. It's certainly not Linux, Networking, etc related... and it's not allowed on WPSE?

@JesseNickles Actually, they bring up a good argument for abandoning wild accusations.

What's on-topic or not on WPSE is a matter for another meta.

Moderators already have tools that allow them to check if a user is receiving a suspicious number of downvotes (or, indeed, upvotes) from another user, and take appropriate action. If you believe you are being unfairly targeted, you can raise a custom mod flag, and a moderator can then use that tooling to check whether you actually are being targeted or not.

@F1Krazy I have done so repeatedly, and also emailed Stack Exchange several times, but the serial harassment continues.

@JesseNickles part of the illegitimate voting on your account has been reverted already. As far as I can tell, there is still a part of the investigation pending, however please be aware that Stack Exchange staff is understaffed, and their response times may be slow. Note that this does not imply that all illegitimate votes against your posts come from the same user, nor moderators will publicly comment on that. However rest assured that the illegitimate activity, no matter where it comes from, will be or has been addressed.

I would also close that question as not being about programming. It is about WordPress plugin configuration. While WPSE does not allow asking questions about specific plugins, this is more general question and the solution is not constrained to a single plugin. I am not going to vote on that question now, but in the future I would still suggest going to WPSE and if necessary asking on their Meta before posting the question for similar problems, than asking such questions on Stack Overflow.
